# Azure VM and App Service integration through VNET

Tags: azure, vnet

SO we have a Ubuntu Virtual Machine on Azure and a Linux App Service, what we want is to integrate both of them throught the port 8983 is there any way of doing this? Maybe trying to get them both on the same vnet?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by integrate, from the port number I'm guessing you want your App to talk to Solr running on the VM?

Either way you will probably want them on the same VNet for security, otherwise you'll have to create a lot of firewall rules on your VM to cater for for all possible external IP addresses your App Service could have.

A VNet will have been created for your VM and you should be able to add the App Service to that through the Portal, also bear in mind you have to be on a Standard or high App Service plan to enable VNet integration.

See here for more info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Comment: Thank you for your response, i already tried to add the vnet of the virtual machine on the App Service but it gives this error: Failed to add delegation to the existing subnet.:
Delegations of subnet /subscriptions/Subscription/resourceGroups/RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/VNET/subnets/default cannot be changed from [] to [Microsoft.Web/serverfarms] because it is being used by the resource /subscriptions/Subscription/resourceGroups/RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/interface/ipConfigurations/ipconfig1.

Comment: @rubennunes I believe you need an unused subnet on the vnet for this to work so if you only have one that the VM uses you'll need to add another to the VNet - see the Regional VNet Integration section on the link in the answer

Comment: Ok so point of the situacion, i created a new subnet on the virtual network that is attached to the Virtual Machine and attached the Virtual Network to the App Service with the new subnet, how to i test the communication throught the port 8983 from the App Service to the VM?

Comment: Well you'll need to open port 8983 on the VM firewall and allow VNet traffic and then your app will need the IP (from the VNet) of your VM then make your requests and debug from there. There will be a default name "AllowVnetInBound" you can use in the firewall rule.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ensure that port 8983 is listed in `WEBSITES_PORT` under **Application Settings** for your web app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-faq#custom-containers